# Register the MouseListener and MouseMotionListener so a JPanel properly handles mouse events

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouse, mouselistener

Im trying to teach myself some basic java by working through this Exercise 14.17 here

[Basic Java Exercise](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780132770873/gui-components-part-1/ch14lev1sec25)

Im stuck on one simple thing which is where it says

**register the MouseListener and MouseMotionListener so the JPanel properly handles mouse events.**

Ive already written 3 methods

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
```

How exactly do i register the MouseListener and MouseMotionListener?

Thnaks

Comment: Look at the examples from the `Swing tutorial`. You've been given a link to the tutorial in your past questions so use the tutorial as a resource BEFORE posting new questions. Or another option is to search the forum/web for examples that use a MouseListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may implement **MouseListener** and **MouseMotionListener** interfaces in your class. And after that you must override all methods from implemented interfaces.

[How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

[How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

Simple sample of code:

```
class YourClass extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```